# why ref = Database.database().reference() must be inside viewDidLoad func

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In ViewController.swift, I try to create ref

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {
  var ref: DatabaseReference!
  ref = Database.database().reference() //ERROR: EXPECTED DECLARATION
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    }
}
```

It shows an error "Expect declaration".

But if I move ref = Database.database().reference() to inside viewDidLoad, it works. Why?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {
  var ref: DatabaseReference!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that what you want to achieve is this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {
var ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
}
```

Your problem is that you want to assign value to previously declared property in "declaration" block.

It works in second case because you have already declared property and you give it a new value in one of your methods. `viewDidLoad` is just one of any other methods you could have done it in.

You might want to read language reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351) especially **Stored Variables and Stored Variable Properties**